# Change image margin in Typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

When creating a 'Text & Images' element in Typo3 how can you adjust the left/right margin around the images?

The default margin between text and images is too small, is there a line I can add to the template to set a custom margin or something else?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can simply add your own CSS file and override desired margins.

Comment: More specifically, it seems I need to change the margin of the text container. This is auto-generated depending on the size of the image. I have background color in the text and the image margin will not affect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use css_styled_content then you can configure this with constants.

```
styles.content.imgtext.textMargin = 10
```

Just over the backend or over TS:

[image]

[image]

Valid constants:

https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/static/constants.txt

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you happen to have any suggestions for my (Tumbleweed) question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791730/typo3-css-styled-content-override-for-images

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS, just inspect the HTML code, each image layout has it's set of classes, so you can easily override it.

Comment: When the image is set beside the text, typo3 generates css that floats the image and sets the margin of the text to the width of the image plus a bit. The images are all variable sizes so I can't see how I would change this with css alone?

Comment: After a bit more investigation I see you can set the image margin. My problem with this is that my headings use a background color and this does not get affected by the image margin, only the actual text does... any ideas?

Comment: Which version of TYPO3? have you got it online ? it's hard to guess what is your problem... I'm able to override CSS without problem.