# Typo3 Record spacing / margin setting

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Specifically In Typo3, I am trying to reduce the amount of space between 2 text records that are directly on top of each other. Basically the text records create rows for entering text, and when you add a row underneath another, typo3 creates a buffer space between them. How do I reduce that buffer or margin, other than putting the lines of text in the same record? I believe we are using 6.2.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this over the TYPO3 Backend. The person/company who did the website implementation has to style this over CSS. (Or yourself, if you know CSS)

Its different if you use a text/image content, and want to change image margin. If your project use css_styled_content you can change this with constants in the backend. (If you have enough permission) See this answer:

[Change image margin in Typo3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407976/change-image-margin-in-typo3/)